# Почему не выводится переменная на сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Есть локальный сервер. Если в запросе написать `127.0.0.1/?com=ls` то в терминале должна выполниться команда `ls`.
У меня получилось передать инфу от `ls` на сервер, но она выводится только в консоль. Почему `console.log(ls)` срабатывает, а `response.write(ls)` нет?

```
var url = require("url"),
    http = require('http'), 
    process = require('child_process'),
    qs = require("querystring"),
    fs = require('fs'),
    port = 8080;

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    var query = url.parse(request.url).query;
    params = qs.parse(query);

    if(params.com=='ls'){
        process.exec('ls', function(err, ls){
            console.log(ls); response.write(ls);
        });
    }
        response.end();   
});

server.listen(port);
console.log('Browse to http://127.0.0.1:' + port);
```

Comment: Потому что асиннхронность. У Вас сначала отрабатывает `responce.end();`, и только после этого вызывается коллбэк. Но в этот момент попытка вызвать `responce.write()` уже ни к чему хорошему не приведет.

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: В данном случае будет достаточно переместить вызов `responce.end()` внутрь коллбэка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `response.end()` не будет работать метод `response.write()` и node.js будет "ругаться" на это, но сервер при этом падать не будет.

```
if (params.com === 'ls') {
    process.exec('ls', function(err, ls){
        console.log(ls); response.write(ls);
    });
}
response.end();
```

В Вашем случае `response.end()` вызывается первым.

Так как Вы вызываете команду **ls**, то вероятнее всего, Вы можете получить ответ частями и просто перенести `response.end` в callback вместо `response.write` будет не грамотно.

Я бы сделал следующим образом:

```
if (params.com === 'ls') {
    process.exec('ls', function(err, data){
        console.log(data);
        response.write(data);
    }).on('close', function () {
        // Всё прошло успешно. Все клиенту уже передали.
        // Может просто закрыть соединение.
        response.end();
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        // обработка ошибки
        // и закрытие соединения
        console.log(err);
        response.end();
    })
}
```

---

#### Одно дополнение:

Не стоит `child_proccess` именовать как `process`, т.к. такой объект уже есть на `global`. И в нем очень много полезных методов и переменных.
Очень часто берут отдельный метод этого модуля, например, как в Вашем случае, exec и уже пользуются им.

И это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

`var exec = require('child_process').exec;`